# Capturing std::function objects in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, lambda, clang

Below code fails with BAD_ACCESS when I call s_capture_void_int() in the last line and I do not understand why. I suppose that when I assign lambda expression to a global variable it supposed to copy itself together with captured values. So in my understanding dangling references should not appear. But it looks like I'm missing something.

```
std::function<void()> s_capture_void_int;
void capture_void_int (const std::function<void(int)>& param)
{
    s_capture_void_int = [param]() {
        param(1);
    };
}
void capture_local_lambda()
{
    auto local_lambda = [](int) {
    };
    s_capture_void_int = [local_lambda]() {
        local_lambda(1);
    };
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_lambda_captures )
{
    //Case 1: this works
    auto func2 = [](int){};
    {
        std::function<void(int)> func2_fn(func2);
        s_capture_void_int = [func2_fn]() { func2_fn(1); };
    }
    s_capture_void_int();

    //case 2: even this works.
    capture_local_lambda();
    s_capture_void_int();

    //case 3: but this fails.
    auto func3 = [](int){};
    {
        std::function<void(int)> func3_fn(func3);
        capture_void_int(func3_fn);
    }
    s_capture_void_int(); //<- it crashes here
}
```

I don't understand two things here:

- If crash happen because of func3_fn goes out of scope then why case 1
  and 2 works?
- If I change this code to std::function (note no parameter) then it works ok. Could it be a compiler bug?

Comment: It works fine with GCC 4.8.2 and Clang 3.3 (+ verified by Valgrind :))

Comment: hmm.... this is weird. I tried to run this code in my iOS project in iOS Simulator (arch i386) and also in clean command line tool (arch=x86_64) and it crashes in the same way. Clang --version gives meApple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a compiler bug. It [works fine in GCC](http://ideone.com/Hn5RUC). Perhaps the `param` in `capture_void_int` is incorrectly captured by reference (since it's a reference) when it should instead be captured by value.

Comment: Can I know what's wrong in capturing as reference? Could u please explain a bit. Even I am facing the same issue

Comment: @BhavithC `func3_fn` is scoped to the block which declares it. If `capture_void_int` only captures a reference to it (instead of correctly capturing by value), that reference becomes dangling at the end of the block, and so the subsequent outside-the-block call to `s_capture_void_int()` goes through the dangling reference and UB ensues.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who come across same problem. This is indeed a compiler bug and I found simple and stupid workaround. Workaround is not tested but at least my program does not segfault right away on a first call to std::function.
Problem manifest itself with clang shipped with Xcode 5.0.2 and 5.1 compiler. gcc 4.8 and possibly stock clang does not have this problem. Simplest possible program to trigger problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> buggy_function;
/*
void workaround (const std::function<void(int)>& param)
{
    auto a = [&,param]() {
        param(1);
    };
}
*/
void trigger_bug (const std::function<void(int)>& param)
{
    buggy_function = [&,param]() {
        param(1);
    };
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto func3 = [](int){};
    std::function<void(int)> func3_fn(func3);
    trigger_bug(func3_fn);
    buggy_function();
    return 0;
}
```

If you uncomment 'workaround' function it magically start working. Order of functions is important, workaround function have to be before any other functions using std::function. If you put 'workaround' below 'trigger_bug' then it stop working.

Comment: Did you file a bug report for this? I am seeing some strange behavior that is related to this but am unsure if its the same bug. Would be interested to see if you filed it if its still open.

Comment: I filed a bug report to Apple and then they reported they fixed it. Unfortunately I cannot find any links to the bug report in my mailbox :(

Comment: No problem. It ended up I had another bug in my code and it was not a compiler issue in my case.